# FUNCION NO SIRVE CUANDO INPUTS SON CREADOS AUTOMATICAMENTE

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen dia, tengo el siguiente script que me autocompleta los nombres de unos productos traidos con ajax de mysqli al digitar las primeras 2 letras en todos los inputs que tengan la clase "autocompletar_input_producto"

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.autocompletar_input_producto').typeahead(
  {
    minLength: 2,//minimos caracteres para que empiece la busqueda
    offset: true,
    order: "asc",
    hint:true,
    accent: true,
    items: 9999,
    source: function (query, result)
    {
      $.ajax({
        url: "../PHP/autocompletar_info_producto_existente.php",
        data: 'query=' + query,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function()
            {
          $('#div_estado_consultar_producto_por_nombre').html("Consultando producto...");
        },
        success: function (data)
        {
          if(data=="producto no encontrado"){$('#div_estado_consultar_producto_por_nombre').html("Producto no encontrado");return;}
          result($.map(data, function (item)
          {
            $('#div_estado_consultar_producto_por_nombre').html("");
            return item;
          }));
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

tengo la siguiente tabla la cual tiene una sola fila donde hay un input con mencionada clase y me autocompleta perfectamente

```
<table id="tabla_items_salida_productos">
   <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>PRODUCTO</td>
    <td>CANT</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="autocompletar_input_producto" id="input_producto_salida_1"></input></td>
    <td><input id="input_cant_salida_1" class="input_pequeno"></input></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

resulta que con un boton el usuario puede crear mas filas pues puede necesitar 2,3, 5 etc cantidad de productos, mencionadas filas se crean perfectamente, el problema es que no hace la accion de autocompletar en los nuevos inputs que se generan, ya revisé en el inspector y efectivamente los nuevos inputs si quedan con la clase "autocompletar_input_producto", este es el script que me hace eso

```
function agregar_filas_a_tabla()
{
  //cuento filas de la tabla
  var numero_de_filas = $("#tabla_items_salida_productos tr").length;
  console.log("numero de filas tabla:"+numero_de_filas);

  var tabla = $('#tabla_items_salida_productos');

  tabla.append("<tr><td>"+numero_de_filas+"</td><td><input class='autocompletar_input_producto' id='productofila"+numero_de_filas+"'></input></td><td><input id='cantidad_fila"+numero_de_filas+"' class='input_pequeno'></input></td></tr>");
}
```

[image: Inspeccion de el input generado automaticamente]

Segun veo el script de autocompletar si sirve si el input estaba ahi pero no si fue generado dinamicamente, alguna idea que puede ser?

Gracias!

Comment: El problema es sencillo, pero acá esta tarde así que algún otro miembro de la comunidad ya se habrá dado cuenta de ello... y lo mas seguro es que de aquí a unas horas tengas la solución si no pues aquí te la comento..., lo que pasa es que cuando tu generas nuevos inputs también debes agregarle el evento oyente a los nuevos generados, en tu caso elementos de una tabla, puesto que estos no estaban presentes a la hora de que jQuery hiciese el anadido por clases de eventos oyentes, asi que no los toma en cuenta.

Comment: Una opción es que en vez de dejar tu función anónima para ponerle directamente los eventos con esa clase que usas, declarar una función con nombre y ponerle a los nuevos campos que vayas a agregar el listener, esa función.

Comment: @Riven o sea tengo que ponerle algo en el atributo a los inputs creados dinamicamente?

Comment: Ummm te dare un ejemplo, cuando tu pusiste por ejemplo $('.autocompletar_input_producto').typeahead()... etc, lo que hiciste hay fue anadirle un listener a todos los elementos que tuviesen la clase autocompletar_input_producto, esto mismo es lo que debes hacer con los nuevos input, solo que poniéndole la función que deseas que se ejecute cuando se cliquea en lo que deseas, no conozco el evento typehead, pero asumo que es un listener que no conozco de jQuery... en caso de que no sea asi, solo debes usar el evento click de jQuery para agregar un listener a tus nuevos elementos.

Comment: O algun otro tipo de evento que desees... por ejemplo keyup, keydown, el que mejor venga para la ocasión, aunque creo que el mejor para ese caso es el de tipo click...

Comment: @Riven el typeahead es una libreria que cuando digitas por ejemplo en este caso dos caracteres, el se ejecuta para autocompletar, con el evento click entiendo que entonces funcionaria dandole click al input?

Comment: Exacto, pero pues en tu caso si el typehead es un listener de una libreria, basta con que pongas eso mismo que esta dentro del typehead como una funcion aparte, y que dentro del typehead llames a esa funcion, y a la hora de crear nuevos elementos html, simplemente asignas un nuevo evento typehead por cada uno de los nuevos elementos html a los que quieras agregarle el evento, donde dentro del typehead tendrias la llamada a la funcion que ejecuta todo tu ajax...

Comment: o sea creo una funcion normal justo antes de minLength: 2 lo cual es una propiedad de esa libreria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenemos los eventos oyentes normales, los cuales lo que hacen es añadir un valga la redundancia, `evento oyente` a un elemento HTML, la declaración de un evento oyente en javascript puro seria de la siguiente manera:

```js
const clickeame = document.getElementById("clickme");
let x = 1;

//Anadimos el evento oyente:
clickeame.addEventListener("click", ()=>{

  console.log(`Me haz clickeado: ${x} vecez!`);
  x++;
});
```

```html
<button id = "clickme">clickeame!</button>
```

Esto seria un evento oyente, una accion que se le indica a un elemento que debe ejecutar cuando pase el evento del tipo especificado, en este caso fue de tipo click.

Si pasasemos esto a jQuery seria asi:

```js
let x = 1;

//Anadimos el evento oyente:
$("#clickme").click(()=>{
  console.log(`Me haz clickeado: ${x} vecez!`);
  x++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "clickme">clickeame!</button>
```

Como vemos es parecido a esto que tienes aquí:

```
$('.autocompletar_input_producto').typeahead(
  ...
  ...
  etc etc...
)
```

Es decir que al parecer estamos usando `typehead` como un evento oyente, no he escuchado quejas de que esto no te sirva asi que supongo que jQuery lo puede usar como un evento oyente...

Entonces lo que te pasa es lo siguiente, miremos el siguiente codigo:

```js
/*
  Tenemos inicialmente 5 botones, y jquery soporta anadirles a todos directamente
  desde una clase un evento oyente, por lo cual a todos se les puede anadir el mismo
  evento a la vez con solo especificar la clase:
*/

$(".boton").click(()=>{

  console.log("hola!");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "boton">click1!</button>
<button class = "boton">click2!</button>
<button class = "boton">click3!</button>
<button class = "boton">click4!</button>
<button class = "boton">click5!</button>
```

Eso funciona correctamente, pero que pasa si ahora añadimos algún botón nosotros mismos desde el codigo??, funcionara??, vamos a ver:

```js
/*
  Tenemos inicialmente 5 botones, y jquery soporta anadirles a todos directamente
  desde una clase un evento oyente, por lo cual a todos se les puede anadir el mismo
  evento a la vez con solo especificar la clase:
*/

$(".boton").click(()=>{

  console.log("hola!");
  const newBtn = document.createElement("button");
  
  //Creamos el boton y lo anadimos a la ventana...
  newBtn.textContent = "click nuevo!";
  newBtn.className = "boton";
  document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "boton">click1!</button>
<button class = "boton">click2!</button>
<button class = "boton">click3!</button>
<button class = "boton">click4!</button>
<button class = "boton">click5!</button>
```

Oops!, vemos que no funciona pese a que tienen la misma clase!, esto es justo aquello que te esta pasando...

Lo que pasa es que cuando nosotros creamos un nuevo elemento, sea con `innerHTML`, con `appendChild`, o lo que sea... lo creamos como si fuese un bebe recién nacido el cual no esta vinculado a sus hermanos, es decir, **no ha aprendido a caminar, y no le hemos dicho que lo haga.**

Para solucionar esto debemos hacer que nuestro elemento crezca, y nosotros decirle: hey!, quiero que hagas esto!

Un ejemplo sencillo de como solucionar el anterior código **para poder que lo puedas aplicar al tuyo**, es simplemente crear una función aparte con un nombre, la cual será la encargada de que nosotros podamos decirle a nuestros nuevos elementos bebes que queramos que hagan una cosa determinada, y que se queden vinculados al resto del grupo:

vamos a hacer el mismo codigo pero funcional, para que cada vez que agreguemos un nuevo boton, este sea funcional como el resto:

```js
/*
  Tenemos inicialmente 5 botones, y jquery soporta anadirles a todos directamente
  desde una clase un evento oyente, por lo cual a todos se les puede anadir el mismo
  evento a la vez con solo especificar la clase:
*/

//Creamos la funcion que hara todo el proceso que queremos...
function imprimirHolaMundo(){
  
  //Hacemos la funcionalidad
  console.log("hola mundo!");
  
  //Agregamos el nuevo boton
  const newBtn = document.createElement("button");
  newBtn.textContent = "click nuevo!";
  newBtn.className = "boton";
  document.body.appendChild(newBtn);
  
  //Le anadimos nuestro evento al nuevo boton:
  $(newBtn).click(imprimirHolaMundo);
}

$(".boton").click(imprimirHolaMundo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class = "boton">click1!</button>
<button class = "boton">click2!</button>
<button class = "boton">click3!</button>
<button class = "boton">click4!</button>
<button class = "boton">click5!</button>
```

Como vemos ahora funciona para todos nuestros botones, espero esta información sea de ayuda... quizá mas tarde edite la respuesta y ponga un poco mas de contexto...

Comment: Excelente, incluso anoche me puse a leer y entendi casi todo esto y con el ejemplo ratifico que no sabia eso de los eventos a los nuevos elementos del DOM, la cuestion es que todos los ejemplos que hay, como en tu caso, son con eventos click mostrando botones, en mi caso son inputs en los cuales se ejecuta el listener typehead al digitar los 2 primeros caracteres de una palabra escrita, Typehead es un listener de una libreria de Twitter llamada Twitter typehead, es posible hacerlo asi tambien?

Comment: Por supuesto amigo.